# Bluetooth discoverable with Android-TV

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-tv

I developed an app using Bluetooth in android that works fine, but I encounter some issue when I try it in Android TV.

According to [Bluetooth tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html), I used this to make my device discoverable:

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

It works fine in normal device, but in Android TV, I get an `ActivityNotFoundException`:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE (has extras) }
```

If I understand well, this exception means that there isn't an activity by default to ask the request to the user (I think the default dialog to ask the permission).

So is there a way to create our own *kind of* activity (to handle this behavior) or may be not ask the permission to the user. Or of course, may be my approach is totally wrong.

I don't know if it's useful but I'm developing on the Nvidia SHIELD TV.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to an issue in your manifest. You'll need to declare one of the Activities in your app to have the capability to receive an Intent from

```
act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE
```

Check out this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138916/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-no-launcher-activity-found-manifest-file-issu) for more information about how to declare Activities in your manifest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's still not working. This kind of intent is not required for normal device so I don't think it's required here.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with the ANDROID 6.0 MARSHMALLOW and bluetooth. I had a similar problem : I could'nt perform a discovery with my app on the Android TV but it worked fine with my phone(and I had no Exeptions). I drop the ANDROID 6.0 MARSHMALLOW and went to the 5.3 and it works after that.